# Hiding wp-login.php in wordpress

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

I am trying to hide `wp-login.php`,So that when someone do mysite/wp-login he should not be redirected to the login page.I have seen several plugins for it like `Lockdown WP` and `Stealth Locker` but that didn't worked,I googled and found that I have to make changes in the .htaccess file,but that also didn't worked out,Anyone who can tell me how to do this,If I found a plugin that would be great.
[I used this link for .htaccess](http://www.phpmagicbook.com/hide-wordpress-wp-admin-login-page/)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is add a few lines to the functions.php of your theme, or add a must use plugin that has code something like this:

```
// Change the login url
add_filter( 'login_url', 'custom_login_url', 10, 2 );

function custom_login_url( $orig_url, $redirect ) {
    return '/newlocation/';
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: The arguments are only used internally by WordPress. You shouldn't need to change them.  $orig_url is what WordPress expects the login url to be. $redirect is the destination the user should go to after the log in is complete. Be sure you urlencode $destination if you are going to use it.